# remove dataframe rows where value is much lower than surrounding rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
Date          Data
2016-04-29    12
2016-04-30    13
2016-05-01    2
2016-05-02    11
2016-05-03    12
2016-05-04    3
2016-05-05    14
```

In the datafrme above, I want to remove those rows where the row value dips below adjacent 2 rows by an average of 8 units e.g. the values in row corresponding to dates 2016-05-01 and 2016-05-04 are at least 8 units below immediately surrounding 2 rows. The result should look like:

```
Date          Data
2016-04-29    12
2016-04-30    13
2016-05-02    11
2016-05-03    12
2016-05-05    14
```

Comment: Why did you choose "8" as the threshold?

Comment: 8 is arbitrary, it can be thought of as an argument that will be passed to a function. If you want you can use some sort of outlier detection as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [pandas.Series.diff](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html).

I would do it like this:

```
>>> df
            Data
Date            
2016-04-29    12
2016-04-30    13
2016-05-01     2
2016-05-02    11
2016-05-03    12
2016-05-04     3
2016-05-05    14

>>> df[(df.Data.diff().fillna(0) > -8) & (df.Data.diff(-1).fillna(0) > -8)]
            Data
Date            
2016-04-29    12
2016-04-30    13
2016-05-02    11
2016-05-03    12
2016-05-05    14
```

### Explanation

The first expression computes row difference taking second minus first, etc. Then replacing the `NaN` in the first row.

The second expression computes row difference taking first minus second, etc. Replacing the `NaN` in the last row. I filter out rows where both expressions result in values below a given threshold.